# Inserting a hyphen between time strings in a list

Tags: php, regex, string

I need some help with a formatting function.  I need to be able to take the input (function argument) and format the string to something else.  Here's my options:

```
7am7pm
10am10pm
OFF
```

So, depending on what is selected, I want the regex to meet the following output criteria:

```
7am-7pm
10am-10pm
OFF
```

In other words, I need a hyphen inserted between the times and the original could be either `[0-9]{2}` or `[0-9]{1}`, so I'm guessing something like `[0-9]{1,2}`, but I'm unsure how to create the function and use it in PHP.

Comment: Will you encounter times like 12:20pm? Or are these always on the hour?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world for some tools that help with designing simple regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
preg_replace("/(\d{1,2}(am|pm))(\d{1,2}(am|pm))/", "$1-$3", $string);
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/BBwW4eEE

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version using [assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), so it only has to inject one character:

```
return preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)/', "-", $arg);
```

It looks only for the position in the string where a letter `?<=` precedes and a number `?=` follows.

Comment: `[a-z]` could be replaced with `m` (love short regular expressions ;))

Answer (score 1):

This should handle the times for you (and you'd manage "OFF" with a simple if statement):

```
$output = preg_replace('/^([0-9]{1,2}(am|pm))-?([0-9]{1,2}(am|pm))$/i', '$1-$3', $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function format_date($date)
{
if( $date == 'off' ) return 'off';
return preg_replace( '/^(\d{1,2}\w{2})(\d{1,2}\w{2})$/' , '${1}-${2}' , $date );
}
```

I'm presuming you're saying the input will look like the first box, and should be formatted like the second?